# Firebase for tvOS without Cocoa Pods

Tags: firebase, tvos

Are there Firebase Frameworks specifically built for tvOS like https://firebase.google.com/download/ios? Right now, I am trying to use Firebase without CocoaPods. I have been successfully linking Crashlytics and Fabric frameworks without issue. When I attempt to link Firebase, I get the following error...

```
ld: in FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o), building for tvOS, but linking in object file (FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o)) built for iOS, file 'Firebase/ios/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore' for architecture arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not publish pre-built binaries for tvOS.

Details about tvOS support at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#tvos-macos-and-catalyst

Follow the open issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4550

**Update March 2020:** The Firebase zip distribution includes tvOS slices since the 7.4.0 release. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases/tag/7.8.1 for the current version.